# como obtener el valor de un input type checkbox en php enviado desde un formulario

Tags: php, array, post, checkbox

desde la base de datos cargo el valor del input checkbox pero cuando lo desactivo y cambio su valor a 0 al enviar el formulario por POST en el array que imprimo no me sale el nombre y el valor de ese elemento, pero si lo envio activado si me sale el nombre y el valor.
EJEMPLO del array POST si el checbox esta activado o checkeado

```
Array(
   [titulo-cabezera] => Caribe S.A.S
   [sub-titulo-cabezera] => viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera caribe supermercados
   [parrafo-cabezera] => viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro. Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo du                       
   [texto-boton-cabezera] => Muy lejos, más allá de las montañas de palabras, alejados
   [cabecera-checked] => 1
   [formulario] => modificar-informacion-cabezera)
```

Y este es el array del POST si el checbox no esta activado o no checkeado

```
Array(
   [titulo-cabezera] => Caribe S.A.S
   [sub-titulo-cabezera] => viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera caribe supermercados
   [parrafo-cabezera] => viéndole don Quijote de aquella manera, con muestras de tanta tristeza, le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro. Todas estas borrascas que nos suceden son señales de que presto ha de serenar el tiempo y han de sucedernos bien las cosas; porque no es posible que el mal ni el bien sean durables, y de aquí se sigue que, habiendo du                                   
   [texto-boton-cabezera] => Muy lejos, más allá de las montañas de palabras, alejados
   [formulario] => modificar-informacion-cabezera)
```

como se puede observar en este array desaparece el item [cabecera-checked]
mi duda es, como hago para que permanezca visible el item  [cabecera-checked] en el array del POST y solo cambie su valor ya sea 0 0 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es, antes de usar el array con los datos del formulario, valides si ese campo viene incluido en el array. Propongo hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$array_post = $_POST;
if (!isset($POST['cabecera-checked'])) {
   $array_post['cabecera-checked'] = 0;
}

//Código usando los valores del formulario desde la variable $array_post
```

Espero te sirva mi ejemplo. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias @diego-saravia fue muy util tú respuesta.